# Rstudio package.install error, cannot load shared object file

Tags: r, linux, rstudio, archlinux

On endeavourOS, I am attempting to install the package "RStoolbox" in R, this package requires the package "exactextractr". When attempting to install either, the installation for "exactextractr" fails, as it requires loading the "terra.so" library in R. The file, however, does exist and is located in the folder indicated by the installer.

```
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
  unable to load shared object '/home/benja/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/terra/libs/terra.so':
  libgdal.so.32: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Calls: <Anonymous> ... namespaceImport -> loadNamespace -> library.dynam -> dyn.load
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘RStoolbox’
* removing ‘/home/benja/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/RStoolbox’
Warning message:
In i.p(...) :
  installation of package ‘/tmp/Rtmp3nJPHa/file408758b470c3/RStoolbox_0.3.1.9999.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

The problem appears to be permission related. I installed these packages using sudo R, and the package installation was successful for the R session contained in the terminal instance. However, the installation of the packages did not carry over to Rstudio's list of installed packages, and I could not later use these installed packages in a regular script.

How do I go about getting these two packages installed into my regular Rstudio?

Edit: attempted reinstalling the terra package to see if it fixed the problem, installation and loading of terra package gives me this error:

```
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Warning: libarrow.so.1000: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (GDAL error 1)
Warning: libarrow.so.1000: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (GDAL error 1)
Warning: libarrow_dataset.so.1000: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (GDAL error 1)
Warning: libarrow_dataset.so.1000: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (GDAL error 1)
Warning: libarrow.so.1000: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (GDAL error 1)
Warning: libarrow.so.1000: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (GDAL error 1)
Warning: libarrow_dataset.so.1000: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (GDAL error 1)
Warning: libarrow_dataset.so.1000: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (GDAL error 1)
```

Comment: Do you have `gdal` (OS package, not R package) installed? Even if `terra.so` exists, it appears to rely on `libgdal.so.32` which does not exist (or you do not have permissions to see it).

Comment: gdal is installed and functioning. The terra package is also installed and functioning without problems. The problem is specifically with the installer seeming to need superuser privileges to access terra.so, as a sudo R does allow me to successfully install the exactextractr package in the terminal environment. Runing Rstudio as superuser breaks Rstudio's interface and does not allow the installation.

Comment: Show us the permissions.

Comment: ... specifically, the permissions of where-ever `libgdal.so.32` is stored (and its directory). If it is readable, then is it in a non-standard location, not referenced by `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`?

Comment: I do not have libgdal.so.32, but, libgdal.so, libgdal.so.33 and libgdal.so.33.3.7.0, all in the /usr/lib/ folder, which has the standard root permisions set by the OS, I have not edited them, nor have I placed any of my libraries in a nonstandard location. I installed gdal using yay and all other packages and libraries using package.install() in Rstudio.

Comment: Okay ... it would appear that `terra.so` is compiled against `libgdal.so.32`, and you have a newer version installed. I suggest that this is an OS question, not-so-much R or RStudio. I suggest you look into either _downgrading_ your `libgdal` installation or finding another way to get `terra.so` installed so that it uses the current version of GDAL on your system.

Comment: Thank you for your support. I managed to get exactextractr by installing it directly from AUR, which I did not know you could do:

yay -S r-exactextractr

loading exactextractr still gives me the libarrow.so.1000 error even though I have installed arrow and Terra and sf no longar give this error.